# Check if a file has been uploaded?

Tags: networking, chromium

Is there anyway for me to tell if a particular file has been uploaded from just my desktop? I'm using Ubuntu and uploaded the file with Chromium.

Comment: Where are you uploading to?

Answer (score 1):

There is a http 200 response to http uploads via a website using chromium. If the web server isn't responding then it's either failed or the web server is broken.

You could use firebug to see the http messages using it's net tab:

[image]